# mysql limit offset, result is disordered

Tags: mysql, limit, offset

#### I have a table which have 31M data,when I try like this:

`select id from class limit 20 offset 0;`

I got the result is not ordered,the result like this "13,18273785,29046580...",why it's not "1,2,3,4,...,20"?

Btw,at another small table,I got the correct result which like "1,2,2,4,...,20",The normal table has less than 10,000 rows of data,The incorrect table has more than 30000,000 rows of data.Any idea? Because mysql transaction isolation mechanism? thanks

I know I can use the order by to get the data I expected,why in the table which have a bit of data like 3000 rows,the limit and offset can get the data I expected,but the another table 30,000,000 can not get ordered

Comment: mysql version is 5.7.19

Comment: The LIMIT clause is used in the SELECT statement to constrain the number of rows in a result set - not from the db - you need an order by or the outcome will be indeterminate.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks ,But why the another small table which used limit offset can get the ordered data?

Comment: Indeterminate ie lucky - all data is stored as unordered sets , you need an order by to impose order (irrespective of any indexes)

Comment: maybe the question I describe the question is not clear,I know I can use the order by to get the data I expected,why in the table which have a bit of data like 3000 rows,the limit and offset can get the data I expected,but the another table 30,000,000 can not get ordered

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ORDER BY` clause e,g,:

```
SELECT id 
FROM class 
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried, I can get the correct results, but after adding order by id after spending too much time

Comment: @Anteoy Do you have any index on `id` column? If not, you can create one

Comment: If `order by id` takes too many seconds, perhaps your ID column is not primary key or is not indexed.  @Anteoy

Comment: @Anteoy by the way, this is another question. If you think this answer has solved your problem, you can accept it and ask a new question.

Comment: @Darshan Mehta Thanks for your answers,I have the index for my id ,And maybe the question I describe the question is not clear,I know I can use the order by to get the data I expected,but the why? I just have more than 30,000,000 rows for this table ,So it's very slow,by the way ,why in the table which have a bit of data like 3000 rows,the limit and offset can get the data I expected.

Comment: @Anteoy In your other table the data may be indexed by Id or the Id column may be the clustered index so they rows when returned without Order BY will default to 0,1,2,3. But if you don't specify the order its left up to the way in which the database has ordered them.  What other question do you have?

Comment: @Usman Mutawakil In the two tables,they both are indexed by Id,I don't found any diffrent between them except the data rows's count.Any other 
help idea?

Comment: @Anteoy Is Id the primary Index in both? is Id the Clustered Index in both?

Comment: @Usman Mutawakil show index from consumer.class:`# Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part, Packed, Null, Index_type, Comment, Index_comment
'class', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '28663644', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''`;show index from consumer.student:`# Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part, Packed, Null, Index_type, Comment, Index_comment
'student', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '3582', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'student', '0', 'id_UNIQUE', '1', ...
`

Comment: @Usman Mutawakil I am sorry for the bad format,the both have primary key,and the annother have a another unique index,both of them I guess the have not the cluster index

Comment: The one that has the extra unique index what order do you get on select? Is that the one with the 1,2,3,4?

Comment: I just use "SELECT * FROM consumer.student limit 20 offset 0" without any oder,I got 1,2,3,4

Comment: @Anteoy: Anyway, the only way to have a query return a guaranteed ordered result is `ORDER BY`. You may be "lucky" that your other query returns rows ordered without it, but that query is still incomplete and unreliable then and it can happen any day that it returns the rows unordered. Fix that other query by adding an `ORDER BY` clause, such as you have fixed this one now.